# Julia package GpABC: abc-example fail

Tags: julia

I wanted to try Julia GpABC package. There are some examples on GitHub: https://github.com/tanhevg/GpABC.jl/blob/master/examples/abc-example.ipynb

I used the In[1] and In[2] from the above and then tried to run simulator function, but I get an error.

Here is the exact code I used:

```
# ~/GIT/GIT_Schistoxpkg.jl_1.2.15/src/ABCexample.jl
#
# ABC settings
#
using GpABC
using OrdinaryDiffEq
using Distances
using Distributions
using Plots
using StatsBase
using Printf
pyplot()

true_params =  [2.0, 1.0, 15.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 100.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0] # nominal parameter values
priors = [Uniform(0.2, 5.), Uniform(0.2, 5.), Uniform(10., 20.),
          Uniform(0.2, 2.), Uniform(0.2, 2.), Uniform(0.2, 2.),
          Uniform(75., 125.), Uniform(0.2, 2.), Uniform(0.2, 2.), 
          Uniform(0.2, 2.)]
param_indices = [1, 3, 9]  #indices of the parameters we want to estimate
priors = priors[param_indices]

#
# ODE solver settings
#
Tspan = (0.0, 10.0)
x0 = [3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
solver = RK4()
saveat = 0.1

#
# Returns the solution to the toy model as solved by OrdinaryDiffEq
#
GeneReg = function(params::AbstractArray{Float64,1},
    Tspan::Tuple{Float64,Float64}, x0::AbstractArray{Float64,1},
    solver::OrdinaryDiffEq.OrdinaryDiffEqAlgorithm, saveat::Float64)

  if size(params,1) != 10
    throw(ArgumentError("GeneReg needs 10 parameters, $(size(params,1)) were provided"))
  end

  function ODE_3GeneReg(dx, x, par, t)
    dx[1] = par[1]/(1+par[7]*x[3]) - par[4]*x[1]
    dx[2] = par[2]*par[8]*x[1]/(1+par[8]*x[1]) - par[5]*x[2]
    dx[3] = par[3]*par[9]*x[1]*par[10]*x[2]./(1+par[9]*x[1])./(1+par[10]*x[2]) - par[6]*x[3]
  end

  prob = ODEProblem(ODE_3GeneReg, x0 ,Tspan, params)
  Obs = solve(prob, solver, saveat=saveat)

  return Array{Float64, 2}(Obs)
end

#
# A function that simulates the model 
#
function simulator_function(var_params)
    params = copy(true_params)
    params[param_indices] .= var_params
    GeneReg(params, Tspan, x0, solver, saveat)
end

simulator_function([2.0, 15.0, 1.0])
```

It leads to an error message:

```
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type ODESolution{Float64, 2, Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Nothing, Nothing, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Vector{Vector{Float64}}}, ODEProblem{Vector{Float64}, Tuple{Float64, Float64}, true, Vector{Float64}, ODEFunction{true, var"#ODE_3GeneReg#7", LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED), Nothing}, Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}}, SciMLBase.StandardODEProblem}, RK4, OrdinaryDiffEq.InterpolationData{ODEFunction{true, var"#ODE_3GeneReg#7", LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED), Nothing}, Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Vector{Vector{Float64}}}, OrdinaryDiffEq.RK4Cache{Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}}, DiffEqBase.DEStats} to an object of type Float64
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, ::Static.StaticFloat64{N}) where {N, T<:AbstractFloat} at ~/.julia/packages/Static/pkxBE/src/float.jl:26
  convert(::Type{T}, ::LLVM.GenericValue, ::LLVM.LLVMType) where T<:AbstractFloat at ~/.julia/packages/LLVM/YSJ2s/src/execution.jl:39
  convert(::Type{T}, ::LLVM.ConstantFP) where T<:AbstractFloat at ~/.julia/packages/LLVM/YSJ2s/src/core/value/constant.jl:111
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] setindex!(A::Matrix{Float64}, x::ODESolution{Float64, 2, Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Nothing, Nothing, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Vector{Vector{Float64}}}, ODEProblem{Vector{Float64}, Tuple{Float64, Float64}, true, Vector{Float64}, ODEFunction{true, var"#ODE_3GeneReg#7", LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED), Nothing}, Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}}, SciMLBase.StandardODEProblem}, RK4, OrdinaryDiffEq.InterpolationData{ODEFunction{true, var"#ODE_3GeneReg#7", LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED), Nothing}, Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Vector{Vector{Float64}}}, OrdinaryDiffEq.RK4Cache{Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}}, DiffEqBase.DEStats}, i1::Int64)
   @ Base ./array.jl:903
 [2] copyto_unaliased!
   @ ./abstractarray.jl:1024 [inlined]
 [3] copyto!(dest::Matrix{Float64}, src::ODESolution{Float64, 2, Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Nothing, Nothing, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Vector{Vector{Float64}}}, ODEProblem{Vector{Float64}, Tuple{Float64, Float64}, true, Vector{Float64}, ODEFunction{true, var"#ODE_3GeneReg#7", LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED), Nothing}, Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}}, SciMLBase.StandardODEProblem}, RK4, OrdinaryDiffEq.InterpolationData{ODEFunction{true, var"#ODE_3GeneReg#7", LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED), Nothing}, Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Vector{Vector{Float64}}}, OrdinaryDiffEq.RK4Cache{Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}}, DiffEqBase.DEStats})
   @ Base ./abstractarray.jl:998
 [4] copyto_axcheck!
   @ ./abstractarray.jl:1104 [inlined]
 [5] Matrix{Float64}(x::ODESolution{Float64, 2, Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Nothing, Nothing, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Vector{Vector{Float64}}}, ODEProblem{Vector{Float64}, Tuple{Float64, Float64}, true, Vector{Float64}, ODEFunction{true, var"#ODE_3GeneReg#7", LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED), Nothing}, Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}}, SciMLBase.StandardODEProblem}, RK4, OrdinaryDiffEq.InterpolationData{ODEFunction{true, var"#ODE_3GeneReg#7", LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED), Nothing}, Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Vector{Vector{Float64}}}, OrdinaryDiffEq.RK4Cache{Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}}, DiffEqBase.DEStats})
   @ Base ./array.jl:563
 [6] (::var"#5#6")(params::Vector{Float64}, Tspan::Tuple{Float64, Float64}, x0::Vector{Float64}, solver::RK4, saveat::Float64)
   @ Main ~/GIT/GIT_Schistoxpkg.jl_1.2.15/src/ABCexample.jl:50
 [7] simulator_function(var_params::Vector{Float64})
   @ Main ~/GIT/GIT_Schistoxpkg.jl_1.2.15/src/ABCexample.jl:59
 [8] top-level scope
   @ ~/GIT/GIT_Schistoxpkg.jl_1.2.15/src/ABCexample.jl:62
```

Any idea why the example fails?

Comment: I was able to make the simulator_function() work when I removed the type of return, ie return Obs only. But if I continue in the example: In[3] works, however In[4] fails. I get an error from the SimulatedABCRejection(): DimensionMismatch("parent has 101 elements, which is incompatible with size (303,)")
Stacktrace:
 [1] _throw_dmrs(n::Int64, str::String, dims::Tuple{Int64})
   @ Base ./reshapedarray.jl:181
 [2] _reshape
   @ ./reshapedarray.jl:176 [inlined]
 [3] reshape
   @ ./reshapedarray.jl:112 [inlined]
 [4] reshape
   @ ./reshapedarray.jl:116 [inlined] .....

Comment: Note that the notebook in question seems to have been last updated in June 2020 - two years ago. It's likely that parts of its interface (or of the packages it depends upon) have changed in the meantime, hence the errors. I'd encourage you to [open an issue](https://github.com/tanhevg/GpABC.jl/issues) mentioning these errors; that way, the package author might be able to help you out, and update the notebook files too.